# The abc-conjecture as an inequality for inner-products?

Tags: nt.number-theory, matrix-analysis, euclidean-geometry, kernels, abc-conjecture

The abc-conjecture is:

For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $K_{\epsilon}$ such that for all natural numbers $a \neq b$ we have:

$$ \frac{a+b}{\gcd(a,b)}\,\ <\,\ K_{\epsilon}\cdot \text{rad}\left(\frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3}\right)^{1+\epsilon} $$

I have two questions after doing some experiments with SAGEMATH:

1. Is the matrix
   $$L_n  = \left( \frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}\right)_{1\le a,b \le n}$$
   positive definite?
2. Is the matrix:
   $$ R_n  = \left(
       \frac{1}{\text{rad}\left(\frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3}\right)}
           \right)_{1\le a,b \le n} $$
   positive definite?

If both of the questions can be answered with yes, then we would have "mappings"

$$\psi ,\phi: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$

and the abc-conjecture might be stated as an inequality in the inner-product of these mappings:

$$\left< \psi(a),\psi(b) \right>^{1+\epsilon} < K_{\epsilon} \left < \phi(a), \phi(b) \right >$$

which I think would be very interesting.

**Edit**:
I realized that it is better to ask the following question:

Is

$$R^{(\epsilon)}_n := (\frac{2^{\epsilon}}{\text{rad}(\frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3})^{1+\epsilon}})_{1\le a,b\le n}$$

positive definite for all $\epsilon \ge 0$?

If "yes", then we would have:

For all $\epsilon \ge 1$ and all $a \neq b$ the following are equivalent:

$$1) d_R^{(\epsilon)}(a,b) = \sqrt{1-\frac{2^{1+\epsilon}}{\text{rad}(\frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3})^{1+\epsilon}}}>d_L(a,b) = \sqrt{1-2\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}}$$

$$2) \left < \psi^{(\epsilon)}_R(a),\psi^{(\epsilon)}_R(b) \right > < \left < \psi_L(a),\psi_L(b) \right >$$

3. The abc conjecture for $\epsilon \ge 1$ with $K_{\epsilon} = \frac{1}{2^{\epsilon}}$

Related question  [Two questions around the $abc$-conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351847/two-questions-around-the-abc-conjecture)

Also the metrics $d_R^{(\epsilon)},d_L$ would be embedded in Euclidean space.

**Yet another edit**:

It seems that
$$\frac{\phi(n)}{n} = \sum_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{\text{rad}(d)}$$

wher $\mu, \phi$ are the Moebius function and the Euler totient function.

From this it would follow using Moebius inversion, that :

$$\frac{1}{\text{ rad}(n)} = \sum_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)\phi(d)}{d}$$

which *could* (I am not sure about that) be helpful for question 2).

**Edit with proof that $k(a,b)$ is a kernel**:
Let
$$k(a,b) := \frac{1}{\frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3}} = \frac{\gcd(a,b)^3}{ab(a+b)} = \frac{\gcd(a,b)^2}{ab} \cdot \frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b} = k_1(a,b) \cdot k_2(a,b)$$

It is known that:

$$\int_0^1 \psi(at)\psi(bt) dt = \frac{1}{12} \frac{(a,b)^2}{ab} = \frac{1}{12} k_1(a,b).$$
Where $\psi(t) = t - \lfloor t \rfloor  - \frac{1}{2}$ is the sawtooth function.
Hence $k_1(a,b)$ is a kernel.

On the other hand, it is known for example by the answer of @DenisSerre, that $k_2(a,b)$ is also a kernel.

Hence the product $k(a,b) = k_1(a,b) \cdot k_2(a,b)$ is also a kernel.

**Update**:
I found this paper online which is interesting (Set there: $X_a = \{ a/k | 1 \le k \le a \}$ then:  $|X_a \cap X_b| = |X_{\gcd(a,b)}| = \gcd(a,b)$ ) and may be of use for the questions above:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326212690_On_the_positive_semi-definite_property_of_similarity_matrices

Setting in the paper above $A_i = \{ i/k | 1 \le k \le i \}$ we see that $|A_i \cap A_j| = |A_{\gcd(i,j)}| = \gcd(i,j)$  and $|A_i|=i$.
Since in the paper it is proved that:

1. The Sorgenfrei similarity $\frac{|A_i \cap A_j|^2}{|A_i||A_j|}$ is a (positive definite $\ge0$, symmetric) kernel, we have another proof, that $\frac{\gcd(a,b)^2}{ab}$ is a kernel.
2. The Gleason similarity $\frac{2|A_i \cap A_j|}{|A_i|+|A_j|}$ is a (positive definite $\ge0$, symmetric) kernel, we have another proof, that $\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}$ is a kernel.

Using the product of these kernels, we get the new kernel $\frac{\gcd(a,b)^3}{ab(a+b)}$.

**Edit, 05.03.2024**:
It is shown [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449483/abc-conjecture-and-positive-definite-kernels-again), that the abc conjecture for $\epsilon:=1$ and $K_{\epsilon}:=1$, would follow, if it can be shown, that the symmetric function

$$K(a,b) := \frac{2(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)\operatorname{rad}\left ( \frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3}\right )^2} $$

is a positive definite function over the natural numbers. I mention this, because it relates to the question in the following sense:

If $K$ is positive definite, the so is the function:

$$k(a,b) := \frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}K(a,b)$$

as a product of two positive definite functions (where $\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}$ is positive definite as is shown by @DenisSerre ). But then, so is the function

$$\frac{1}{2}k(a,b) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}K(a,b) = \frac{1}{\operatorname{rad}(\frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3})^2}$$

positive definite, which would answer for $\epsilon=1$  the question asked above positively for the matrix $R_n$.

Comment: What is the maximum value of $n$ that you tried with your experiments?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I have tried up to $n=50$. Have you found a counterexample?

Comment: no, I just asked out of curiosity

Comment: $L_n$ is clearly positive definite as it is the Schur product of two PSD matrices (or are you looking for "strict" positivity? that should also be doable). And moreover, it seems $L_n$ is also infinitely divisible because both the gcd matrix and the Cauchy matrix ($1/(a+b)$) are infinitely divisible, thus leading to a Hilbert space embedding. As for $R_n$, I'm not sure what 'rad' does so cannot have a simple answer...

Comment: @Suvrit: Thanks for your comment, which is very helpful. What does "infintely divisible" mean? As for "rad", I will update the question with a hopeful useful observation.

Comment: The $R_n$ matrix is positive definite up to $n=100.$

Comment: @orgesleka Infinite divisibility of a an elementwise nonnegative psd matrix $[x_{ij}]$ means that $[x_{ij}^t]$ is also psd for all $t \ge 0$. It is possible that $R_n^\varepsilon$ ends up not being psd, unless $R_n$ itself is infinitely divisible (which then translates into Hilbert space embeddability of a related distance function obtain by taking elementwise logarithms, etc...)

Comment: @Suvrit thanks. maybe you could provide an answer why Ln is infinitely divisible and how the embedding in Hilbert space works?

Comment: If I get some time, I'll try to type up; or you could have a look at this ancient question of mine and see the essential idea in there already: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75865/applications-of-the-gcd-metric

Comment: @Suvrit: Is it possible to give an explicit matrix $A^T A = L_n$?

Comment: Please restrict to one question per post. BTW the relation $\phi(n)/n=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)/\mathrm{rad}(d)$ is straightforward to verify: both sides are multiplicative functions of $n$, and they agree at prime powers. In the same way, it is straightfoward to verify directly that $1/\mathrm{rad}(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\phi(d)/d$.

Comment: @GHfromMO ok thanks for your comment

Comment: If $\mu(d)\ne0$, then the radical of $d$ is just $d$, so the relation is just the well-known $\phi(n)/n=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)/d$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The matrix $L_n$ is positive definite.

**Proof**. The matrix $G_n$ with entries ${\rm gcd}(a,b)$ is positive definite because of $G=D^T\Phi D$ where $\Phi={\rm diag}(\phi(1),\ldots,\phi(n))$ ($\phi$ the Euler's totient function) and $d_{ij}=1$ if $i|j$ and $0$ otherwise. Then the matrix $H_n$ with entries $\frac1{a+b}$ is positive definite because
$$h_{ij}=\int_0^1 x^{i+j-1}dx$$
and the matrix with entries $x^{i+j-1}$ is positive semi-definite for $x>0$. Finally $L_n=G_n\circ H_n$ (Hadamard product) is positive definite.

Comment: thanks @DenisSerre for your answer

Comment: My comment already provides a proof of $L_n$ being not only positive definite, but infinitely divisible :-)

Comment: @DenisSerre Is it possible to give an explicit matrix $A^TA=L_n$?

Comment: @orgesleka. In principle it is possible to calculate an upper triangular $A$ such that $A^TA=L_n$. This is called the Choleski factorization. It costs $O(n^3)$ operations.

Comment: @DenisSerre: I know of the Cholesky factorization. I was hoping for something more in the lines of $G = D^T \Phi D$ which you gave in your answer.

Comment: @DenisSerre: Dear Professor Serre, I found another proof, that $\frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}$ is a (positive definite $\ge 0$, symmetric) kernel and updated the question. Kind regards, Orges Leka