# The d(abc)-theorem, the abc-conjecture and positive definite kernels over the natural numbers?

Tags: nt.number-theory, matrix-analysis, hilbert-spaces, positivity, abc-conjecture

I noticed in [the work of Hector Pasten, Th.1.11](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.09251.pdf) the $d(abc)$ theorem and have a question, after doing some experiments with sagemath.
Let $s_k(n) = \sum_{d|n}{ d^k }$ be the sum of divisiors $d$ of $n$ to the power $k=0,1,2,3,\cdots$.
Then $s_0(n)$ counts the number of diviosrs.
$s_1(n) = \sigma(n)$ is the sum of divisors etc.
Is it true that for each $k=0,1,2,\cdots$ the following function is a positive definite kernel over the natural numbers?
$$K(a,b) = \frac{1} {s_k \left( \frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3 } \right )}$$ 
? 
I wrote @Pasten (the author of the theorem) and hopefully I will get an answer, but I thought that meanwhile I could ask the question here, and I hope it is ok to share this question here.

Possible attack on this problem through a related problem:
Define $X_a = \{ a/k | 1 \le k \le a \}$. Then $X_a \cap X_b = X_{\gcd(a,b)}$ and $|X_a| = a$. Thus the following functions are proven to be similarities (Encyclopedia of Distances), some of which also are positive definite kernels over the natural numbers:

Example of such similarities are:

1. $s_{Si}(a,b) = \frac{\gcd(a,b)}{\min(a,b)}$ =  Simpson similarity
2. $s_{BB}(a,b) = \frac{\gcd(a,b)}{\max(a,b)}$ =  Braun,Blanquet similarity
3. $s_{J}(a,b) = \frac{\gcd(a,b)}{a+b-\gcd(a,b)}$ =  Jaccard similarity
4. $s_{S}(a,b) = \frac{2\gcd(a,b)}{a+b}$ = Sorensen similarity
5. $s_{Cos}(a,b) = \frac{\gcd(a,b)^2}{ab}$ = Squared Cosine similarity

My idea is to define a set $X_a$  for each natural number $a$ and then maybe to make use of known similarities? (This is just an idea and might not lead anywhere).

Thanks for your help!

Related question:
[The abc-conjecture as an inequality for inner-products?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352054/the-abc-conjecture-as-an-inequality-for-inner-products)

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be a kernel over the natural numbers?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: a symmetric, positive definite function over the natural numbers.

Comment: Thanks. $K(a,b)$ is obviously symmetric, and obviously positive, so what's left to prove?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: positive definite

Comment: OK, I know what it means for a quadratic form to be positive definite – what does it mean for a function to be positive definite, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Sorry for not being clear: I mean the matrix $(K(a_i,a_j))_{i,j}$ is positive definite for each choice of natural numbers $a_1,\cdots,a_r$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong for the divisor counting function $\sigma_0$ and $n=73$ as the Gram matrix has determinant $<0$.