# abc-conjecture and positive definite kernels, again?

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory, inner-product, abc-conjecture, experimental-mathematics

One formulation of the abc-conjecture is:

$$\forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}: \frac{a+b}{\gcd(a,b)}< \operatorname{rad}\left ( \frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3}\right )^2 $$

Let us define:

$$K(a,b) := \frac{2(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)\operatorname{rad}\left ( \frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3}\right )^2} $$

I have [checked in Sagemath](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9kE1ugzAQhfdI3GHEyiZWKekOlROEG0RVZGITjQhjZJyovX1tflJE01qyZM289z3PKN1A2zIpal7EEfhjtbtZgjy9nNVYz5jc1TyO4kh5sZWK0UbbW6NYb7HTJ4V3HIwdvOZhORye8bNAkmmdjvhsSUvTN3_3wTu5q-qJez-72MP2L43_4DrpGIm23QB92eInOx7nZUBjLEhA8gPTRbNc0C7nH2O5_lWe-aFJ62b-GsLnJGyAjAM2_aCq-AsOp94M6PDuF6cbJHSa8UUfjl8qOZYE36KERVlAIoD4JA7R3Z_R63i_TxIdfy_HB_GyzNeyTaqEATu8SovuC5obnR0aKhIRBhg5Ysbwb4U1n3I=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) up to $n=100$ that the matrix

$$(K(i,j))_{1 \le i,j \le n} \text{ is positive definite }$$

and up to $1\le a,b \le 100$ that :

$$K(a,b)\le 1$$

In the Encyclopedia of Distances the word "similarity" is described as:

A similarity $s:X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined in the Encyclopedia of Distances as:

1. $s(x,y) \ge 0 \forall x,y \in X$
2. $s(x,y) = s(y,x) \forall x,y \in X$
3. $s(x,y) \le s(x,x) \forall x,x \in X$
4. $s(x,y) = s(x,x) \iff x=y$

So one possible formulation of the empirical observation above might be:

$$K \text{ is a positive definite kernel and a similarity function with } K(a,a)=1$$

From this formulation the abc conjecture in the variant above follows, because:

$$K(a,b) \le K(a,a)=1 \rightarrow \frac{(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)\operatorname{rad}\left ( \frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3}\right )^2} \le \frac{1}{2} < 1$$

**Since in the definition of the similarity function, some of the properties are easy to prove for $K$ such as 1. and 2. and from 3. follows abc, I am asking if it is possible to prove $\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{\text{ property 4. and / or}}$  that $K$ is positive definite function?**

Thanks for your help.

**Edit**:
I think that $4.$ can be proved by considering that if $K(x,y)=1$ and assuming there exists a prime $p$ which divides $x$ but not $y$, leads to a contradiction.

**Second edit**:
The abc conjecture (in the version above) would follow, if one could prove that the function

$$K(a,b) := \frac{2(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)\operatorname{rad}\left ( \frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3}\right )^2} $$

is positive definite over the natural numbers.

**Proof:**
If $K$ is a positive definite function over the natural numbers, then by the [Moore-Aronszajn theroem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Moore%E2%80%93Aronszajn_theorem) , there exists a Hilbert space $H$ and a feature mapping $\phi: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow H$ such that:

$$K(a,b) = \left < \phi(a),\phi(b) \right >_{H}$$

But by [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) we get:

$$K(a,b) = |K(a,b)| = |\left < \phi(a),\phi(b) \right >_{H}|$$
$$\le |\phi(a)||\phi(b)| = \sqrt{K(a,a)K(b,b)} = \sqrt{1 \cdot 1} = 1$$

But then we get by division of $2$ and application of the last inequality:

$$\frac{(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)\operatorname{rad}\left ( \frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3}\right )^2} \le \frac{1}{2} < 1$$

hence it would follow that:
$$\forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}: \frac{a+b}{\gcd(a,b)}< \operatorname{rad}\left ( \frac{ab(a+b)}{\gcd(a,b)^3}\right )^2 $$

**Modified question**:
Is there a way to speed up the computations to try and test if the Gram matrix for $n=1,\cdots,10000$ is positive definite?

Here is my code so far, but it is rather slow:

```
# inductive cholesky decomposition
def rad(n):
    return prod(prime_divisors(n))


def kk(a,b):
    return (2*(a+b)*a**1*b**1/gcd(a,b))*1/rad(a*b*(a+b)/gcd(a,b)**3)**2

def notPositiveDefinite(a,b):
    return rad(a*b/gcd(a,b))

#kk = notPositiveDefinite

def grammat(kk,n):
    return matrix([[kk(a,b) for a in range(1,n+1)] for b in range(1,n+1)],ring=QQ)


PHI = dict([])

def phi(n,useN=False):
    if n in PHI.keys():
        return PHI[n]
    
    if n==1:
        if not useN:
            x = vector([sqrt(kk(1,1))])
        else:
            x = vector([sqrt(kk(1,1)+0.0)])
        PHI[n] = x
        return x
    else:
        w = CC(n-1)**(-1)*vv(n-1)
        lw = list(w)
        if not useN:
            lw.append(sqrt(kk(n+1,n+1)-w.norm()**2))
        else:
            lw.append(sqrt(kk(n+1,n+1)-w.norm().n()**2).n())
        x = vector(lw)
        PHI[n]= x
        return x

def vv(n):
    return vector([kk(i,n+1) for i in range(1,n+1)])
    

CCDict = dict([])    
    
def CC(n):
    if n in CCDict.keys():
        return matrix(CCDict[n])
    mm = []
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        vi = list(phi(i))
        if len(vi) < n:
            vi.extend((n-i)*[0])
        mm.append(vi)
    M= matrix(mm)
    CCDict[n] = mm
    return M
    
    


for n in range(1,200):
    print(n,all(x in RR for x in phi(n,useN=True)))
    #print(grammat(kk,n).rational_form())
```

Comment on code:
It is based on inductive Cholesky decomposition as describe below and keeps track in a dictionary if the $\phi(n)$ or $C_n$ have already been computed. It uses float approximation for greater speed and in the last step we check if each component of the vector $\phi(n)$ is a real number. If it is for all $1 \le k \le n$ then we conclude that the Gram matrix of $n$ is positive definite. If it is not, then at least the Gram matrix for $n$ is not positive definite:

inductive Cholesky decomposition to find an embedding $\phi(n)$ for each number $n$:

Equation 1):
$$\phi(n+1) = \left(\begin{array}{r}
{C_{n}^{-1} v_n} \\
\sqrt{k(n+1,n+1)-{\left| {C_{n}^{-1} v_n} \right|}^{2} }
\end{array}\right)$$

Equation 2):

$$v_n = \left(\begin{array}{r}
k(1,n+1) \\
k(2,n+1) \\
\cdots\\
k(n,n+1)\\
\end{array}\right)$$

Equation 3):
$$C_n = \left(\begin{array}{r}
\phi(1)^T \\
\phi(2)^T \\
\cdots\\
\phi(n)^T\\
\end{array}\right)$$

Equation 4):
$$\phi(1) := \sqrt{k(1,1)} e_1$$

If we assume that the function $k$ is positive definite, then this inductive method, should give us the vectors $\phi(a),\phi(b)$ such that under the normal inner product we have:

$$k(a,b) = \left < \phi(a), \phi(b) \right > $$

Comment: The word "again" in the question refers to the 3 years older question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352054/the-abc-conjecture-as-an-inequality-for-inner-products? from me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conjecture about the positive definiteness of the kernel above is wrong as one has $\det(G_{192})<0$:

```
def rad(n):
    return prod(prime_divisors(n))

def kk(a,b):
    return (2*(a+b)**1/gcd(a,b)*1/rad(a*b*(a+b)/gcd(a,b)**3)**2)

def grammat(kk,n):
    return matrix([[kk(a,b) for a in range(1,n+1)] for b in range(1,n+1)])


n=192

print("n = ",n,sign(grammat(kk,n).det()))
```